# PHP 7 SQLServer and Fastcgi

Tags: php, sql-server, apache

I have a WAMP Server installed in Win2012 Serv , PHP 7.1.9 and Apache 2.4.29. The PHP drivers for SQL Server (php_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll etc) work perfectly - but if I switch the Apache server to use FastCGI then the SQL Server drivers stop working, flip back to non Fastcgi - everything fine. I need to switch to Fastcgi because the HTTPD service in apache 2.4.25 and above crashes and restarts over and over and over , sometimes 30 times a day , but in fastCGI mode its solid and stable.
What am I doing wrong ? is there something to add to Fastcgi config to use SQLSRV drivers ? The error is the usual - unknown function sql_srv_query() , indicating that the SQLSRV drivers are dead or not there....

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, please read **[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)** in the **[Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)** then **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47366062/edit)** your question.

Comment: Sorry dont get it , my question is fairly clear --

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue - turns out that the phpinidir directive in wamp needs to be the apache\apache2.4.29\bin  and not the php directory. When changing to use fastcgi make sure to reference the Apache php.ini sym link in the config options .